# Angular Js ng-model not updating variable in an inner function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have the following code in my controller:

```
appControllers.controller('myCtrl', [ '$scope',
function($scope) {
    $scope.timeFreeze = false;

    $scope.ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws");

    $scope.ws.onopen = function() {
        $scope.ws.send('{...}');
    };

    $scope.ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
        var received_msg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
        //...do something with the data...
        console.log($scope.timeFreeze); // This is ALWAYS false!!! Why?
        if ( $scope.timeFreeze === false) {
            $scope.$apply();
        } else {
            console.log("Frozen!"); // This never runs!!!
        }
    };

    $scope.ws.onclose = function() {
        console.log("Connection is closed...");
    };
}
```

]);

and in my html I have:

```
<div>
    <label>Freeze?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="timeFreeze"/>
</div>
```

What is meant to happen is that when the checkbox is ticked, the code should output "Frozen!" in the console. Unfortunately this code is NEVER run! The $scope.timeFreeze is always false despite me setting the ng-model for the checkbox.

Comment: Try using dot notation. Something like ng-model="socket.timeFreeze" and $scope.socket.timeFreeze.

Comment: +1 to jeff. Your input must be inside an ng-repeat or ng-if or any other directive that creates its own child scope. So you're setting the value of the timeFreeze attribute of the child scope instead of modifying the controller scope.

Comment: @JBNizet Well its under the ng-controller="myCtrl" implicitly as I am angular routes

Comment: @jeff I tried both $scope.timeFreeze and $scope.ws.timeFreeze [when you said socket I assume u meant ws], both did not work. Still shows up as false

Comment: Yes, but ng-if/ng-repeat are also under the scope of myCtrl, and create their own child scope. Show us your complete html if you want us to spot the bug exactly. But the fix of jeff should work fine. Use `$scope.time = {freeze: false };` in your controller, and use `ng-model="time.freeze"` in your view.

Comment: Awesome that seems to work. But I'm not sure why I have to set up an intermediary property such as time.freeze instead of going to freeze directly. When I took the code out of the ng-view directive (as you suggested) it seemed to work fine with just "timeFreeze". Is there a better way as it seems a bit odd me setting up an intermediary value each time I want to adjust the controller scope as supposed to the child scope.

Comment: The 2-way binding for primitive does not work as people expect. The child value does not does propagates up. This is a fundamental issue with JavaScript, not of angular. You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: I think I understand "why" it was not working. I just wanted a better way of accessing controller variables. Is there one?

Comment: Okay after reading some of it I think there isn't really a better way (considering as well the fact that the dot thing is also a best practice). Thanks for your help. If someone posts it as an answer i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Do you mind if one of you guys post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer so it can be marked:

Try using dot notation. Something like ng-model="socket.timeFreeze" and $scope.socket.timeFreeze. JB Nizet used a better naming convention so I'm gong to borrow from him:

In your controller:

```
$scope.time = {freeze: false };
```

In your view:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="time.freeze">
```